# We don't get any error message or exception, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python

```
print(10 .__add__("1"))
```

The output comes as :

```
-NotImplemented
```

Why this as in just this,  no error no exception

Comment: ["If one of those methods does not support the operation with the supplied arguments, it should return NotImplemented"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)

Comment: I think this is a bit different - you need the space between `10` and `.__add__('1')` or you just get an invalid syntax error. Some oddity in the CPython implementation?

Comment: Oh, no - everyone is right - you just need the space to distinguish a decimal point from getting the attribute in the case of a string literal, so it looks odd. You can't add a string to an int - so it is NotImplemented duplicate.

Comment: I have put the space there,  guess it's not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(10 .__add__("1"))
```

the `("1")` specifies the string,since it is enclosed in a double quotes..

10 indicates integer....

the function to add string and integer is probably may not be implemented earlier..so this is why python shows `NotImplemented`

```
print(10 .__add__(1))
```

and the space also doesn't matter..!!!!

```
print((10).__add__(1))
```

the above two codes also will work